# How do you dynamically search a MySQL database with REGEXP-LIKE?

Tags: php, mysql, regexp-like

How can I dynamically search a table with REGEXP-LIKE? This is a simplified version of my code right now but it only works if I'm using the exact keyword:

```
$city = "%{$_POST['city']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT player,points FROM users WHERE city LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->execute();
```

Consider this table

```
id | player     | city             | points 
1  | John Doe   | Miami            | 26
2  | Jane Doe   | Los Angeles      | 26
3  | Alfred Doe | Jersey           | 28
4  | Jeff Doe   | Miami Beach      | 25
5  | Bruno Doe  | East Los Angeles | 29
```

If user searches with keyword `Jersey Shore` result should be

```
Alfred Doe
```

If user searches with key word `Miami` or `Miami Shores` both results should be

```
John Doe
Jeff Doe
```

If user searches with `Los Angeles` result should be

```
Jane Doe
Bruno Doe
```

Comment: The content of the question does not exactly match your title. This shows how to do regexp in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html - but inside your question it seems you use some kind of abstraction layer (maybe DBAL on PHP). Consider refining the title, the tags and specially showing all the investigation you have already done.

Comment: @XaviMontero: Thank you. The issue I'm facing is all the solutions I come across are hardcoded and know everything in advance, including the docs. I've been struggling doing this dynamically with prepared statements.